# Spring Data MongoDB custom repository implementation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, autowired

I want to replace SimpleMongoRepository implementation provided by Spring Data with my custom implementation.

```
public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;
    private MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation;
    @Autowired
    private Set<QueryFilter<T>> filters;
    @Autowired
    public BaseRepositoryImpl(
            Set<QueryFilter<T>> filters,
            MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation,
            MongoOperations mongoOperations
    ) {
        this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations;
        this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
        this.filters = filters;
   }

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(
            MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation,
            MongoOperations mongoOperations
   ) {
        this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations;
        this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
    }

    ...
}
```

in configuration:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(
    basePackages = {"com.mycomp.mymodule.repository"},
    repositoryBaseClass = com.mycomp.mymodule.repository.BaseRepositoryImpl.class
)
public abstract class MyModuleConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
...
```

My goal is to apply some filters on queries for all repositories. Everything work but for my implementation I need one more parameter injected to my implementation class.

I have filter class implementing QueryFilter and I expect him to be loaded to filters field but it does not happens...